# error: 500 SERVER ERROR on unique register URL in Laravel 8.*

Tags: laravel

I made random and unique register URL to add users to my app. Everything worked on my localserver but when I migrated app to server it crashes.

Error:

```
THAT LINK HAS EXPIRED OR IS NO LONGER VALID!
```

After adding Request $request to my register controller, now I've got all the time my error code page.

My register function on RegisterController:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function register(Request $request) {
        abort_unless($request->hasValidSignature(), 403, 'That link has expired or is no longer valid!');

        //they can register now
      }
```

My URL generator:

```
$url = URL::signedRoute(
            'register',
            now()->addMinutes(30));
```

**Error is because of my $url generator does not work, for not known for me reasons.**

Comment: Did you check the `laravel.log` file or webserver logs to figure at why the error 500 is shown?

Comment: @MaartenDev I just checked it on local server, error is the same, I edited post

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way of accessing request object in laravel controller.
You can read this [laravel document](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests) about how to access the request in the controller.

> To obtain an instance of the current HTTP request via dependency injection, you should type-hint the Illuminate\Http\Request class on your route closure or controller method. The incoming request instance will automatically be injected by the Laravel service container:

So, to access the request object in controller, you have two options:

1. Use Dependency Injection.

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

/**
 *
 1. @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 */
public function register(Request $request)
{
   // Your Logic
}
```

2. Use Laravel Helper Function

```php
public function register()
{
    request()->hasValidSignature()
}
```

If you just do `public function register($request)`, this is called route parameter. It refers to the parameter that you define in the route, such as `{user_id}`. Here is the example of how route paramter works

> Sometimes you will need to capture segments of the URI within your route. For example, you may need to capture a user's ID from the URL. You may do so by defining route parameters:

```php
Route::get('/user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return 'User '.$id;
});
```

And if you take a look at your registration route, it probably looks like this `Route::post('/register')`, and as you see there is no route parameter. When your controller function runs, it expects a parameter called `$register` and you do not have any. This is what the error says "Too few Argument"

```
Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::register()
```

Comment: So right now after editing my function by adding (Request $request) should I also make route that would use it? After editing it at least I'm getting right page and right error, meaning that my function works thanks to you, still there is problem with wrong ValidSignature(with my logic that's the only reason for page to fail)

Comment: Could you possibly look again on my question Sir?

Comment: Can you post your route?

Comment: I changed everything so it works on route now, Route::post('register', [App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController::class, 'register'])->name('register')->middleware('signed'); ------Added also signed in middleware, still with the same result "Invalid signature"